# How to query IP range in Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to query IP range from:172.16.0.0 to 172.31.0.0 in ELK

I try two query methods, but fail.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "DstIP": "172.(3[0-1]|1[6-9]|2[0-9]).*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "DstIP": {
        "gte": "172.16.0.0",
        "lte": "172.31.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can query IP  range in ELK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For range queries to work correctly on IP values it is necessary to define the field data type as [`ip`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html).**

Below is the working example with mapping, sample docs, and search query.

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dest": {
        "type": "ip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

Then I've taken a couple of sample documents like this:

```
{ "dest":"172.16.0.0"}
{ "dest":"172.31.0.0"}
{ "dest":"172.21.0.0"}
{ "dest":"172.1.0.0" }
{ "dest":"172.12.0.0"}
```

**Search Query :**

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dest": {
        "gte": "172.16.0.0",
        "lte": "172.31.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result :**

```
 "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "foo4",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "dest": "172.16.0.0"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "foo4",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "dest": "172.31.0.0"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "foo4",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
               "dest": "172.21.0.0"
            }
         }
      ]
```

Comment: @disney82231 did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for IP range filter query like `192.168.0.0/16` you can use the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html) directly. If you need the aggregate the data you can use [ip range aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-iprange-aggregation.html).

```
PUT /my-index-000001?pretty
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ip_addr": {
        "type": "ip"
      }
    }
  }
}


PUT /my-index-000001/_doc/1?pretty
{
  "ip_addr": "192.168.1.1"
}


GET /my-index-000001/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "ip_addr": "192.168.0.0/16"
    }
  }
}
```