# Query to get the set of records from a filed of ip addresses based on the give CIDR range using in Elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

A query to get the elastic search db results based on the give CIDR Range. Can anyone help me on this?
e.g:
addresses { type : "IP_V4", value: "0.0.0.1"}

Request id CIDR range say 0.0.0.0/32 then then should return all the addresses with the value as ips within this range.

Comment: Add some samples and the query you tried. Though I didn't down vote, please always tried to add what you tried here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For range queries to work correctly on IP values OR on CIDR ranges it is necessary to define the field data type as [ip](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html).**

Below is the working example with mapping, sample docs, and search query.

**Mapping :**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dest": {
        "type": "ip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Sample Data :**

```
{ "dest":"209.173.53.170/20"}
{ "dest":"209.173.53.167/20"}
{ "dest":"209.173.53.172/20"}
```

**Search Query :**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dest": {
        "gte": "209.173.53.165/20",
        "lte": "209.173.53.170/20"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result :**

```
"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "dest": "209.173.53.170/20"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "dest": "209.173.53.167/20"
            }
        }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

According to your updated question :

> Request id CIDR range say 0.0.0.0/32 then then should return all the
> addresses with the value as ips within this range.

You can try out this below search query :

```
 {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "dest": {
        "lte": "209.173.53.172/20"  --> change the value according 
                                         to your data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query will return all the IP addresses that are less than or equal to `209.173.53.172/20`

Comment: @Madhavi did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you

Comment: i added the structure in description. By the way what is mappings here as I am getting "failed to parse search source. unknown search element [mappings]".

Comment: @Madhavi From the error, it seems as if there is some issue in the URL that you have taken for creating explicit mapping, please go through this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html to know more about mappings in elasticsearch. You need to simply create a new index and define the mapping in it (same mapping as I have mentioned above), after which you can insert data in it and run the search query.

Comment: @Madhavi can u please tell, that the search result that I have got above is the same as that of what u wanted OR were you looking for something else? And which version of elasticsearch you are using ?

Comment: @Madhavi If u are using postman, then for creating an explicit mapping for a new index , u need to have a PUT request, with this URL ```http://localhost:9200/{{index-name}}```, and in the body add the mapping as provided above in the answer.

Comment: Hey @Madhavi can you please answer my above questions ?

Comment: The response you shared is again a CIDR range right but i don't have any cidr range values in the elastic search addresses.value field,  it contains IP addresses. Thats the one thing i observed.

Comment: @Madhavi are u able to resolve your issue? Can you please add some sample data upon which u are performing your search, and can u please mention your search criteria because in the question u said **Request id CIDR range say 0.0.0.0/32**, but in the above comments u are saying **i don't have any cidr range values**. And, are you able to create index with the explicit mapping I mentioned in the answer above ?

Comment: @Madhavi you can also refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62506986/10348758 , if you want to query IP range in Elastic search

Comment: TY for the support. My elastic filed is type keyword ie., string currently. So the straight forward filtering won't be possible. So filtered and done some process to do that  filtering through code. Sorry for  delay in reply.

Comment: @Madhavi thank u for accepting the answer :) Can u please upvote this answer also :)